# Get 2 consecutives frames with av_read_frame()

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, stream, streaming

I am working with rtmp and ffmpeg/libav. I have a clip with a fps of 60 fps where it is made of 2 consecutive video frames and 1 audio frame. The 2 consecutive frames correspond to left and right images toke from 2 cameras (already sync).
I use `av_read_frame` for reading the frame and then if it is a video frame I use `avcodec_decode_video2`(I know it is deprecated but it still works and I will replace it later). Now, since I have to put the 2 video frames side by side, I wait until the 2 frames are completely read and I put them together with OpenCV. The problem is that it seems that I always read only the left frames interrupted sometimes by the right frames. I searched a bit the problem and it seems that is related to the flushing of the decoder. So, I tried to flush the decoder by using empty packages or using `avcodec_flush_buffers` but the situation is even worst, I get the left and right images but only few frames.
In the following I put a sample of my code:

```
bool left = false;
while(true)
{
  ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
  if(ret < 0)
    break
  if(pkt.stream_index == video_index)
  {
    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, &pkt);
    if(got_frame)
    { 
      if(!left)
      {
        //I SAVE THE LEFT FRAME
        left = true;
      }
      else
      {
        //I PUT THE LEFT AND RIGHT FRAME TOGETHER
        left = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out what is the problem: basically the clip/stream I am trying to read is made of 1 I frame and then P frames that actually are I frames, because each frame represents Left and Right.
I cannot force anything with `av_read_frame`, so I have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing adjacent frames (left and right) may have same PTS values. You may first buffer the frames then fetch according to PTS value (look for same values) after correctly fetching the frames it may be trivial to adjoin them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, no the pts time of 2 consecutive frames is different.